# Custom "Simple" Error Messages in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

A Spring Boot 1.5.1 (non-web) application was written to extract database rows. Tomcat datasource is auto configured because it is included in the `pom.xml` i.e.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Therefore, these keys are required,

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${db.driver}
spring.datasource.url=${db.url}
spring.datasource.username=${db.username}
spring.datasource.password=${db.password}
```

and when any of these variables, e.g. ${db.driver} or ${db.url}, is missing, the application would dump the whole error stack.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'db.driver' in string value "${db.driver}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
...
```

This made fixing simple problems difficult because lots of text were churned and cluttered the actual problems.

How do I make Spring Boot report custom simple error messages defined by me when, say, ${db.driver} or any of the variables is not defined anywhere in, for example, application.properties or JVM environment? Thanks

**Update 1**
I given some thoughts after the 1st comment. I am not so much as to look to change the exception messages nor prevent them from thrown out into the log. I want to check or intercept the required parameters before they are passed to the actual module to access. Case in point, the data source.

Comment: Exceptions are a universally accepted and understood method for "reporting errors" that are fatal. How would you want it reported otherwise? Are you suggesting it is difficult to read an exception stack trace?

Comment: In general, I never doubt the stack trace is a good way to tell what went wrong. To an uninitiated user, if I can, I will show the least info for him to resolve the problem. It is fine too if the exceptions are intercepted and logged as simple messages in one file and the stack trace goes into the general log file which could be used for bug fixes

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a default value, non existing placeholders will not lead to an exception. Instead the default value is used.

You could set the default for the properties in the properties file where you use them

```
spring.datasource.url=${db.url?localhost:123//whatever}
```

You can than check the properties in a @PostConstruct annotated method or an ApplicationListener and report the error however you want.

But this does not make too much sense, because when spring tries to create a connection to the database it will fail without correct configuration.
Depending on your application, this may already happen during application startup.

Comment: Yes, the failure happens during application startup. I want a hook to the stage in the SpingBoot (SB) where it has resolved all the properties but before it kicks off the JDBC connection pool sequence. Alternatively, I could do a pre-flight check outside of SB but I have to look for all the properties located at various places. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I am aware of default values using `spring.datasource.url=${db.url?localhost:123//whatever}`